# React - What does the callback in forceUpdate do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate), `forceUpdate` has a parameter `callback`.

Is that like `setState`'s second parameter which is called after setting a state? Or what is that for?

I can't find any articles about that.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it like setState's second parameter which is called after setting a state?

Yes it is. The answer is on react source code. If you look at `react/src/ReactBaseClasses` you will see that `setState` and `forceUpdate` are defined like:

```
Component.prototype.setState = function(partialState, callback) {
  // ...
  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');
};

Component.prototype.forceUpdate = function(callback) {
  this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this, callback, 'forceUpdate');
};
```

And if we go on `enqueueSetState` and `enqueueForceUpdate` implementation, we will see that:

```
const classComponentUpdater = {
  isMounted,
  enqueueSetState(inst, payload, callback) {
    const fiber = getInstance(inst);
    const currentTime = requestCurrentTimeForUpdate();
    const suspenseConfig = requestCurrentSuspenseConfig();
    const expirationTime = computeExpirationForFiber(
      currentTime,
      fiber,
      suspenseConfig,
    );

    const update = createUpdate(expirationTime, suspenseConfig);
    update.payload = payload;
    if (callback !== undefined && callback !== null) {
      // ...
      update.callback = callback;
    }

    enqueueUpdate(fiber, update);
    scheduleWork(fiber, expirationTime);
  },
  enqueueReplaceState(inst, payload, callback) {
    ...
  },
  enqueueForceUpdate(inst, callback) {
    const fiber = getInstance(inst);
    const currentTime = requestCurrentTimeForUpdate();
    const suspenseConfig = requestCurrentSuspenseConfig();
    const expirationTime = computeExpirationForFiber(
      currentTime,
      fiber,
      suspenseConfig,
    );

    const update = createUpdate(expirationTime, suspenseConfig);
    update.tag = ForceUpdate;

    if (callback !== undefined && callback !== null) {
      // ...
      update.callback = callback;
    }

    enqueueUpdate(fiber, update);
    scheduleWork(fiber, expirationTime);
  },
};
```

The differences between `enqueueSetState` and `enqueueForceUpdate` are in `update.payload` and `update.tag`.

So yes, the `forceUpdate` callBack has the same behaviour of `setState`'s second parameter.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it like setState's second parameter which is called after setting a state?

The short answer here is: **Yes**, the `forceUpdate()` method takes the same optional argument `callback`, which is of type `Function`, as the `setState()` method (see [ReactBaseClasses](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cae635054e17a6f107a39d328649137b83f25972/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js) implementation).

In the case of `forceUpdate()` the `callback` will be called after the update, whereas for the `setState()` method the `callback` is called after the state is updated. The notable difference here is that the `forceUpdate()` method calls the `enqueueForceUpdate()` method, whereas `setState()` uses the `enqueueSetState()` method.

As [Giovanni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13897065/giovanni-esposito) outlined in his answer, the `update.tag` is set to `ForceUpdate` inside the `enqueueForceUpdate()` method. However, the `update.tag` value is set to `UpdateState` by default in the `createUpdate()` method. As the `ForceUpdate` tag has a higher value (i.e. `2`), it has a higher priority than `UpdateState` (i.e. `0`).

Here are the implementation details for `createUpdate()`, `UpdateState` as well as `ForceUpdate` (see [ReactUpdateQueue.new](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactUpdateQueue.new.js)):

```
...
export const UpdateState = 0;
export const ReplaceState = 1;
export const ForceUpdate = 2;
export const CaptureUpdate = 3;
...
export function createUpdate(eventTime: number, lane: Lane): Update<*> {
    const update: Update<*> = {
            eventTime,
            lane,

            tag: UpdateState,
            payload: null,
            callback: null,

            next: null,
    };
    return update;
}
```